# How does the golang chaincode in the marbles nodejs example works?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I have got this example https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles run locally. I saw that the example downloaded the golang chaincode from https://github.com/ibm-blockchain/marbles-chaincode. And the chaincode was stored on harddisk at /marbles/node_modules/ibm-blockchain-js/temp/unzip.
Could you please explain how the golang chaincode was executed inside the nodejs code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't looked at the Marbles app in detail, but generally speaking, the nodejs code is just a client to the validator network, and the validator is processing the golang based chaincode in a way that is completely decoupled from the nodejs based client.  In this process, the validator downloads/acquires the chaincode and compiles it locally within an isolating container.  You could look at the process like [golang::chaincode]->[nodejs::client]->(network)->[golang::validator]->[golang::container].  So the first and last parts are golang/chaincode related, the stuff that happens in the middle is more or less a transport.  I.e. the fact that the client is nodejs and the validator is golang matter little here.

Answer (score 3):

The Golang code that implements the Marbles chaincode (aka smart contract) does not get executed inside the Node.js app. The chaincode is what the application interacts with to modify state variables stored in the blockchain. State in this case is: what marbles exist, who their owner is, what color it is, etc. But the chaincode itself (the Golang code) is packaged as a docker container, deployed to the blockchain, and is up and running waiting for transactions. The Node.js code constructs and sends these transactions to the docker container, receives results of the chaincode execution, and updates the application view of the current state.

Just FYI, the Marbles app was implemented to demonstrate how to implement an application running on top of the Hyperledger Fabric project. Hyperledger currently only fully supports Golang as it's smart contract language, but more languages are coming soon.

Comment: I run the example locally with bluemix hyperledger network. I saw that the Marbles app downloaded the chaincode from Git repo then unzipped it. Does the marbles app packege the chaincode into a docker container locally as a Non-Validating Peer to communicate with the bluemix hyperkedger network or send the chaincode to the netwotk, and the network make it a container?

Comment: From reading your question, it sounds that you already have the IBM Blockchain on Bluemix service set up. That implies that you have two validating peers and a CA service already in place in Bluemix. Let me know if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: If the setup described above is accurate, then if you are running the Marbles example locally, the reason it downloads and unzips the chaincode is in order to introspect the chaincode and identify the invoke and query function names. This is application level code, not fabric code. Then it constructs a deploy transaction that it sends to the peer rest endpoint. The deploy transaction contains a pointer to the Github repo containing the Marbles chaincode. The chaincode is pulled from the Github repo and deployed to Docker ON the peer. Not inside the Marbles app. Let me know if this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/blob/master/tutorial_part1.md),

[image]

> Interacting with the cc is done with a HTTP REST call to a peer on the
>   network. The `ibc-js` SDK will abstract the details of the REST calls
>   away. This allows us to use dot notation to call our GoLang functions
>   (such as `chaincode.invoke.init_marble(args)`).
>
> The user will interact with our Node.js application in their browser.
>   This client side JS code will open a websocket to the backend Node.js
>   application. The client JS will send messages to the backend when the
>   user interacts with the site.
>
> The backend Node.js will send HTTP
>   requests (via the SDK) to a blockchain peer to carry out the user's
>   actions. The peer will communicate to its chaincode container at its
>   leisure. Note that the previous HTTP request was really a 'submission'
>   of chaincode to be run, it will actually run at a later date (usually
>   milliseconds).
>
> The cc container will carry out the desired operation
>   and record it to the ledger. ie create/transfer a marble.